# Синхронизация двух сетевых папок расположенных на NAS

Tags: сеть, синхронизация, nas

Есть две сетевые папки расположенные в разных местах. У обеих есть статический IP адрес, проброшенные порты и тд (в общем удаленный доступ к этим папкам имеется). Но встал вопрос о их синхронизации. Обычные программы не поддерживают подключение к сетевым данным (ну либо я плохо искал). Сам в этом не силен, поэтому ищу помощь на просторах интернета.

Answer (score 0):

На одном из этих NAS запустить [rsync](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), натравив его на второй NAS.

Параметры какие-то такие:

```
rsync -arv --progress user@remote.server.address:/remote/data local/directory/
```

Для обеспечания безопасности, все нужно [обернуть в SSH-тоннели с авторизацией по ключу](https://bozza.ru/art-190.html)